# Windbg: Printing the breakpoint number which triggered

Tags: windbg, breakpoints

When I run Windbg and it hits a breakpoint, then it prints the number of the breakpoint which triggered it. When I use a conditional breakpoint, I would want to print this as well. Is there some variable that holds the breakpoint number which triggered?

Because when I some ".printf" in the breakpoint condition, then only the stuff that I specify is printed (which is fine), but I would want to know which one it was as well.

Comment: After setting your breakpoints, could you not list them `bl` and then re-enter the breakpoint again and then either `.printf` or `.echo` the ordinal value of the breakpoint? This will redefine the breakpoints

Comment: `.echo` what? That's what I wanted to know. :)

Comment: when you enter `bl` this will list all breakpoints with numeric ordinal value and address, you can set breakpoints then list them and then redefine them and add `.echo` like `bp foo ".echo 'bp 1'"` or `.echo 'foo bp 42'`

Comment: I know that I can use `bl` to look at the list in the window. I wanted to know how I can print the number of the breakpoint from with in a conditional breakpoint. Not how to show the list.

Comment: But once you list the breakpoints you know the ordinal number so you can redefine the breakpoint and add the `.echo` command to output the ordinal number, as far as I know there is no command to output the breakpoint number but you can just add the `.echo` command is my point

Comment: Furthermore you can assign an ID value when you define the [bp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538903(v=vs.85).aspx) and you can `.echo` this as a command parameter when you define the breakpoint so you would know which breakpoint was hit

Comment: Ah, I see now what you mean. Thanks, that's an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define your breakpoints you can specify the `ID` [value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538903%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can then `.echo` this as a command string:

```
bp 42 myDLL!myClass::foo ".echo 'breakpoint 42 hit!!!';gc"
```

You will then know for sure which of your breakpoints was hit.

Alternatively you can list the current breakpoints using `bl` and this will list the breakpoints and display the ordinal number (actually the ID that is assigned if you didn't specify it when defining the breakpoint).

You can use this ordinal number and redefine you breakpoint and `.echo` the ordinal number the sam way as above.

Comment: I'd recommend swapping that `g` with a [`gc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to keep the debugger from mysteriously F5'ing when stepping over that breakpoint.